# Vuejs v-model special characters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Can you escape special characters with v-model? I am seeing an issue where I edit text that I receive from a data call. 'this' is showing as '&'#39;this'&#39' in the textarea when editing. I know of v-html, but can you use that with v-model? If not, what is another option?

Comment: Are you saying you are getting HTML-encoded data and want to convert it to plain text for use in the textarea?

Comment: Yes - I need the user to be able to edit the data returned.  In my current solution, using v-model, 'this' is displaying as '&'#39;this'&#39' causing confusion to the user and also when saving the updated text  '&'#39;this'&#39' is being saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` works like `v-text` and shows all characters while `v-html` let you show the html code.
If you see "this" in you source file/debugger/response the reason might be the encoding or that you try to display json-text. 
Because `&#39;` is the NCR dez. for the character `'` .

`v-model` gives automatic two way binding, if you do not need that you can use one of the other directives.

Comment: I need to be able to use v-model so that the user can update and save.

Comment: Have you checked that your " 'this' " arrives in utf-8 ?

Comment: I doubled checked data format and it was not utf-8. I was able to change the response from the provider and the issue is resolved.

Comment: So the answer resolved your question, would you mind to mark that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have encoded text and you need to convert it to plain text. If it is proper HTML, one common trick is to set it as the `innerHTML` of a scratch div, and then extract the `textContent` from that div. I've created a little helper function in my snippet below to do that.

The text you give looks like it has some extra quotes in it, so there may be some more massaging of the data that you need to do to unpollute it, but the approach is still what I show here: fetch the text, unpollute it, and assign the unpolluted text to the variable you want to edit.

```js
const scratchDiv = document.createElement('div');
function toPlainText(html) {
  scratchDiv.innerHTML = html;
  return scratchDiv.textContent;
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    plainText: ''
  },
  mounted() {
    // fetching code-polluted text
    this.plainText = toPlainText("&#39;this&#39");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea>
  {{plainText}}
  </textarea>
</div>
```