# RegExp to ignore HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I have a string of text

```
<p>This is some text 
  <span style="color: rgb(54, 54, 54);"> and here is a bit more</span> 
  and even more.
</p>
```

and this regexp `<[^>]*>` will grab the following from it.

```
<p> 
  <span style="color: rgb(54, 54, 54);"></span> 
</p>
```

How would I grab the inverse of this instead? I am looking to get the text instead. Been searching all over and have only managed to find people using the above regexp to do a content replace to strip tags.

I'm looking to search the text in my VueJS app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/get-text-node-of-an-element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44955924/392102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you can access the dom use nodeElement.innerText
If you can't then the html will probably be a string, so just use your regex and replace with empty string to get the inverse of that.

```js
console.log('1) ',target.innerText);
console.log('2) ',target.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,''));
```

```html
<div id="target"><p>This is some text<span style="color: rgb(54, 54, 54);"> and here is a bit more</span>and even more.</p></div>
```